# Array loop to determine a range average

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, highcharts

I am working with an array of 25 data points for a JS Chart.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- Subtract the next value from the previous value, i.e. $value[0] - $value[1]
- Take that resulting value and assign it to another array of values
- Take the absolute value of each in the new array and divide by 24.

This creates an range average used within another formula to determine an upper and lower control limit for the chart.

This is originally being calculated in Excel and I need to move this into an array for an online chart of data points.

I pull my array via a query using Codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select('datapoint');
$this->db->from('my_table LIMIT 25');
$this->db->where('gauge=', '18');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

This provides my array which I echo into a line of JavaScript for the chart (HighCharts).

```
data: [<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) { echo $row->datapoint . ',';} ?>],
```

I have tried a for loop found on another stackoverflow question similar to:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
$value = $row->datapoint;
for ($i = 1, $n = count($value); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $value[] = $value[$i] - $value[$i-1];
}
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($value);
echo "</pre>";
```

It is only providing one value that is not close to what I am looking for.

I just need one value which is that array divided by 24 then I can add that value to my chart.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the value of `$row->datapoint`? - Your loop looks very strange.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how your array looks like? Also, why are you using the same variable for storing the results? That'll just push  values (if any) to the already-defined `$values` array.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - The value of `$row->datapoint` is an array of 25 datapoints.  Similar to: 31.80,31.80,31.80,40.12,34.50,23.88,20.08,37.74,30.76,24.32,14.74,28.70,20.44,35.04,29.54,50.22,25.32,29.74,36.34,26.64,31.68,27.78,37.92,31.70,22.86  @amalmurali - The for loop is where I am having the problem so I am sure it is wrong.

Comment: Does working on a single row instead of 25 get you the expected result? if not, please provide the expected output for the array you just posted.

Comment: @YanBerk No because I need all 25 rows of data to determine the range average.  Those data points help determine tolerance levels for the amount of pressure applied to a wire crimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help @ElMarce, but it took a bit more code for it to work.  I had to add a second array and I changed some of the variable names.

This code is to create the Range Average which is then used to determine the Upper and Lower Control Limits of an SPC chart using HighCharts and Codeigniter.  Was this the proper way to solve this issue? I am not sure but it does work for what I need.  Thanks for everyone's help.

```
$rangeArray = array();
$value = array();
$rangeAvg = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $value[] = $row->pull_force;
for ($i = 0, $n = count($value) - 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $rangeArray[$i] = abs($value[$i] - $value[$i+1]);
    $rangeAvg = array_sum($rangeArray) / 24;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$valueDiff = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $value = $row->datapoint;
    for ($i = 0, $n = count($value) - 1; $i < $n; $i++) {

        //Subtract the next value from the previous value, i.e. $value[0] - $value[1]
        //Take that resulting value and assign it to another array of values
        //Take the absolute value of each in the new array and divide by 24.
        $valuesDiff[$i] = abs($value[$i] - $value[$i+1]) / 24;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($valuesDiff);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: your response looks just like what I am trying to accomplish, but I now get a notice that it cannot define the $valuesDiff variable. we are getting there :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad :P. I edited the answer. Keep me updated if it doesn't work

Comment: It currently only outputs a blank array:   `Array ()`  Any ideas?